# Magento 2 : How to Override frontend Template File?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, magento-2.0

[image]I'm developing a custom module in **magento 2**. I need to change the file located in `Magento/Sales/view/Frontend/Templates/Email/Items/Order/default.phtml`.

Comment: sorry @Rahul but I didn't find any file(order.phtml) under this location check it again.

Comment: Are you kidding there is no file in this location can you provide screenshot ?

Comment: @Ramkishan see this screenshot

Comment: where is order.phtml ? there is default.phtml in order folder

Comment: Now you have edit your question. Please provide right information so that we can give answer.

Comment: i want override this default.phtml file

Comment: add Layout file code on that this file is called.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can override using below code in your module.

```
 <referenceBlock name="block_name" >
      <action method="setTemplate">
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_YourModuleName::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
      </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

**block_name**: should be default block name of `order.phtml` template is calling.

**Example**

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit" >
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::address/edit.phtml</argument>
        </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

in my case, i want to override `edit.phtml`. so `customer_address_edit` block name I have used.

**EDIT**
add this code in your `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_Module::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite a template all you need to do is add a template with the same file path to your theme, so adding the template to the location below should overwrite the template you want:

```
/app/design/frontend/YOUR-VENDOR/YOUR-THEME/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

Read more about Magento 2's theme inheritance here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html